# What is the name for the Maya Python library(ies)?

Tags: maya, conventions, pymel

I want to distinguish between the [Python libraries available in Maya](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-C0F27A50-3DD6-454C-A4D1-9E3C44B3C990):

1. *MEL* (the embedded Maya language)
2. *Maya Python libraries* (`maya.cmds`, but also `maya.standalone` and `maya.mel.eval`)
3. *PyMEL* [[*]](https://github.com/LumaPictures/pymel) (`pymel.core` and others)
4. *Maya Python API 1.0* (`maya.OpenMaya`)
5. *Maya Python API 2.0* (`maya.api.OpenMaya`)

Do the Maya Python libraries (item 2) have a name? A name that covers 2, 4 and 5 would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  `import Maya` will give you all of them, though most people start one level down with, for example, `import maya.cmds as cmds`  There are a few more that you missed in your list: `OpenMaya` , the old api, has siblings `OpenMayaRender`, `OpenMayaUI`, and `OpenMayaAnimation` and there's also `maya.util`

You can list the full roster of top-level maya modules like this:

```
import maya
import inspect
maya_modules = {name:mod for name, mod in inspect.getmembers(maya) if inspect.ismodule(mod) }
```

the full list in Maya 2016 is:

```
'OpenMaya': <module 'maya.OpenMaya' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMaya.pyc'>,
'OpenMayaAnim': <module 'maya.OpenMayaAnim' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMayaAnim.pyc'>,
'OpenMayaFX': <module 'maya.OpenMayaFX' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMayaFX.pyc'>,
'OpenMayaMPx': <module 'maya.OpenMayaMPx' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMayaMPx.pyc'>,
'OpenMayaRender': <module 'maya.OpenMayaRender' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMayaRender.pyc'>,
'OpenMayaUI': <module 'maya.OpenMayaUI' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\OpenMayaUI.pyc'>,
'app': <module 'maya.app' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\app\__init__.py'>,
'cmds': <module 'maya.cmds' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\cmds\__init__.py'>,
'debug': <module 'maya.debug' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\debug\__init__.py'>,
'mel': <module 'maya.mel' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\mel\__init__.py'>,
'standalone': <module 'maya.standalone' (built-in)>,
'utils': <module 'maya.utils' from 'c:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\maya\utils.py'>
```

It would of course be trivial to make your own module which imported a subset of those.

Comment: maybe a better question is how do you distinguish between `maya` the Python library and Maya the application? (e.g. in conversation)

Comment: I think most people rarely talk about the maya namespace: if you google around you'll find that about 85% of everything is `cmds` (known as such),  most of the rest is `OpenMaya` or 'api2' for `maya.api.XXX`